# C# - TimeZone Issue in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, timezone

I am facing an issue in timezone. Right now I am saving time zone from client side and stored all DateTime in UTC. It's working properly but when I am trying to convert DateTime for UTC behind time zones like CST, EST, EDT it showing wrong data.

**Issue -**
Let's assume if I did any task at 10 PM EDT and it would be saved in DB as 2 AM(as per UTC) but when I am trying to fetch data for a day and passing current UTC date.

My question is If am trying to fetch data for a day like 11 midnight( from EST) to the current time, but my conversion from UTC to EST is wrong due to UTC 12midnight is yesterday's 8 PM(as EDT 4hr behind from UTC). (From Date[UTC convert to EDT] - 06/07/2017 08:00pm) and To Date - 06/07/2017 11:00 pm) Due to this conversion I am getting data from 8 pm to 11 pm only <- I am expecting from date is 06/07/2017 04:00 AM as per UTC.

**Code -** 
Below is the code for conversion. In from date I have taken utcnow.date only and from a date

**Javascript code -**

```
function setTimezoneCookie() {
            try {
                var timezone_cookie = "timezoneoffset";
                var timeZoneName = "timezonename"

                var tz = jstz.determine();
                var aa = tz.name();
                // if the timezone cookie not exists create one.

                if (!$.cookie(timezone_cookie)) {
                    // create a new cookie
                    $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
                    $.cookie(timeZoneName, aa);
                }
                else {
                    var storedOffset = parseInt($.cookie(timezone_cookie));
                    var currentOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
                    if (storedOffset !== currentOffset) {
                        $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
                        $.cookie(timeZoneName, aa);
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.cookie(timeZoneName, aa);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**c# code -**

```
 fromDate =Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).ToClientTimeZoneinDateTime().ToString();  
                toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(toDate).ToClientTimeZoneinDateTime().ToString();

                ObjectParameter totalRecords = new ObjectParameter("TotalRecords", typeof(int));
                var DetailsList = objDetailsList.GetDetails(loginUserId,locationId, userId, taskType, pageIndex, numberOfRows, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, textSearch, totalRecords, fromDate, toDate);
                if (DetailsList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    string output = BuildJQGridResults(DetailsList, numberOfRows, pageIndex, Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords.Value));
                    response.Write(output);
                }
                else
                {
                    JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
                    List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
                    result.rows = rows.ToArray();
                    result.page = 0;
                    result.total = 0;
                    result.records = 0;
                    response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result));
                }
```

Below is the method of converting UTC time to client timezone

```
public static DateTime ToClientTimeZoneinDateTime(this DateTime dt)
{
    try {               
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"] != null || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezonename"] != null)
        {                  
            var timezonename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezonename"].Value;
            timezonename = timezonename.Replace("%2F", "/");
            var timezoneLocal1 = FindTimezoneName(timezonename);
            TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneLocal1);
            bool isCurrentlyDaylightSavings = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(dt);
            if (isCurrentlyDaylightSavings == true)
                dt.AddHours(1);

            var timeOffSet = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"].Value;

            var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);                  
            return dt;
        }             
        return dt.ToLocalTime();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

No doubt as Timezone handled properly but facing an issue for behind timezone from UTC if end user trying to fetch data after 8 PM EDT. I have attached screenshot as well.

Below img of before conversion -
[image]

Above img of after conversion -
[image]

How do I need to handle this situation?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your code, and conversions of `DateTime`?

Comment: http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: It sounds like your query is using the wrong date. Remember the date in your query should be in UTC as well. Post some sample code for better answers.

Comment: In most cases, one actually needs to do a *range query* to pull back data relative to a *local* date when the data is stored in UTC.  You need to show us a complete example if you want a better answer.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with asp.net or MVC?  Sounds like it is a query problem between your application layer and your database.

Comment: Thanks for you time @gravity. I have provided. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @VictorP - I have provided the complete example. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Please provide your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're converting the wrong direction.  You are converting from UTC to the user's time zone, but your *input* is in the user's time zone, so you need to convert the other direction - from the user's time zone to UTC.  Then your query will show better results.

A few other things:

- Don't convert time zones by trying to add/subtract minutes or hours manually.  Use the conversion functions offered on `TimeZoneInfo`, such as `ConvertTimeFromUtc`, `ConvertTimeToUtc`, etc.  There's no need to test for DST.
- The try/catch shouldn't be in your code at all. Throw an exception if you can't perform the operation.  Don't mask important errors by swallowing exceptions.
- `dt.ToLocalTime()` shouldn't be in your code either.  Never rely on the server's local time zone.
- The offset returned by `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` is the user's *current* offset.  You cannot assume that it's the correct offset for the dates chosen.  You don't that anyway, as you're already getting the time zone name. (You don't need the `timezoneoffset` cookie at all.)
- The time zone name returned by `jstz.determine()` on the client-side is going to be an IANA tzdb identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.  These aren't going to work on the server-side with `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` (unless you are running .NET Core on Linux or Mac).  Conversion to a Windows time zone is required. I see you have a `FindTimeZoneName` function, which I assume is performing the conversion.  You didn't show the details in your code, but I highly recommend you use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to implement that, as it's maintained with changes to time zones.
- Reading cookies and time zone conversion are separate concerns.  Don't bundle them together.

Ultimately, you should have something like this:

```
public static DateTime FromTimeZoneToUtc(this DateTime dt, string timeZone)
{
    var windowsId = TimeZoneConverter.TZConvert.IanaToWindows(timeZone);
    var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(windowsId);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, tzi);
}
```

Or, even better, if you use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), then you don't need to convert time zones at all.

```
public static DateTime FromTimeZoneToUtc(this DateTime dt, string timeZone)
{
    var tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
    var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt);
    return local.InZoneLeniently(tz).ToDateTimeUtc();
}
```

Comment: I need to pass UTC time to DB as per user's timezone like EDT 12midnight for UTC is 4 am. I need to pass UTC 4 am according to user time zone as user's start time is from UTC 4 am.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You need to convert from local to UTC.  That's what my answer shows you how to do.

Comment: I have done changes but it showing me wrong conversion. Ex - UTC(06/12/2017 12:00AM) to (06/11/2017 04:00AM).
But I want conversion like starting day of EDT i.e 06/11/2017 04:00 AM.

Conversion is true no doubt i.e UTC (06/12/2017 12:00AM) 
 is (06/11/2017 08:00 PM)

Could you please brief me how I can handle this situation?

Comment: I'm really not certain where your confusion lies. You said your database is in UTC (which is good).  So take the client's day `[2017-06-11T00:00:00-04:00,2017-06-12T00:0000-04:00)`, and use the client's time zone to convert to UTC `[2017-06-11T04:00:00Z,2016-06-12T04:00:00Z)`.  Use the UTC values to query the database.  Then in your results, convert values back to the local time zone.  The code you showed is converting the inputs in the wrong direction, and not converting the outputs at all.  You keep asking for the very thing I keep saying.  Are you trying to accomplish something *different*?

Comment: Thanks. I understood your point.Is there any method, using timezone name we can find out live date time of client time zone?

Comment: Yes, you take the UTC time and run it through the conversion methods on `TimeZoneInfo`

Comment: Ok, Matt. Thanks for your valuable time.